# Core class of a JavaScript framework for Single-Page-Applications

Tags: node.js, api, coffeescript

A few years ago I started building a tiny (~300 SLOC) JavaScript framework for scalable and maintainable Single-Page-Applications written in CoffeeScript.

- [GitHub](https://github.com/flosse/scaleApp)
- [www.scaleapp.org](http://www.scaleapp.org/)

It's inspired by the talk "Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture" by Nicholas Zakas. The project was starred on GitHub by some people but that is quite useless since that doesn't give any qualified feedback.

The framework consists of two classes:

- The `Mediator` (responsible for events; similar to node.js `EventEmitter`)
- The `Core` (it mainly starts and stops modules within a sandbox)

Now here is the `Core` class that needs to be refactored:

```
checkType = (type, val, name) ->
  "#{name} has to be a #{type}" unless typeof val is type

class Core

  constructor: (@Sandbox) ->

    # define private variables

    @_modules      = {}
    @_plugins      = []
    @_instances    = {}
    @_sandboxes    = {}
    @_running      = {}
    @_mediator     = new Mediator

    # define public variables

    @Mediator     = Mediator
    @Sandbox      ?= (core, @instanceId, @options = {}, @moduleId) ->
      core._mediator.installTo @
      @

  # define dummy logger
  log:
    error: ->
    log:   ->
    info:  ->
    warn:  ->
    enable:->

  # register a module
  register: (moduleId, creator, opt = {}) ->
    err =
      checkType("string",   moduleId, "module ID")  or
      checkType("function", creator,  "creator")    or
      checkType("object",   opt,      "option parameter")
    if err
      @log.error "could not register module '#{moduleId}': #{err}"
      return @

    if @_modules[moduleId]?
      @log.warn "module #{moduleId} was already registered"
      return @

    @_modules[moduleId] =
      creator: creator
      options: opt
      id: moduleId
    @

  # start a module
  start: (moduleId, opt={}, cb=->) ->

    if arguments.length is 0
      return @_startAll()

    if moduleId instanceof Array
      return @_startAll moduleId, opt

    if typeof moduleId is "function"
      return @_startAll null, moduleId

    if typeof opt is "function"
      cb = opt; opt = {}

    e =
      checkType("string", moduleId, "module ID")    or
      checkType("object", opt, "second parameter")  or
      ("module doesn't exist" unless @_modules[moduleId])

    return @_startFail e, cb if e

    id = opt.instanceId or moduleId

    if @_running[id] is true
      return @_startFail (new Error "module was already started"), cb

    initInst = (err, instance, opt) =>
      return @_startFail err, cb if err
      try
        if util.hasArgument instance.init, 2
          # the module wants to init in an asynchronous way
          # therefore define a callback
          instance.init opt, (err) =>
            @_running[id] = true unless err
            cb err
        else
          # call the callback directly after initialisation
          instance.init opt
          @_running[id] = true
          cb()
      catch e
        @_startFail e,cb

    @boot (err) =>
      return @_startFail err, cb if err
      @_createInstance moduleId, opt, initInst

  _startFail: (e, cb) ->
    @log.error e
    cb new Error "could not start module: #{e.message}"
    @

  _createInstance: (moduleId, o, cb) ->

    id = o.instanceId or moduleId
    opt = o.options

    module = @_modules[moduleId]

    return cb @_instances[id] if @_instances[id]

    iOpts = {}
    for obj in [module.options, opt] when obj
      iOpts[key] ?= val for key,val of obj

    Sandbox =
      if typeof o.sandbox is 'function' then o.sandbox
      else @Sandbox

    sb = new Sandbox @, id, iOpts, moduleId

    @_runSandboxPlugins 'init', sb, (err) =>
      instance = new module.creator sb
      unless typeof instance.init is "function"
        return cb new Error "module has no 'init' method"
      @_instances[id] = instance
      @_sandboxes[id] = sb
      cb null, instance, iOpts

  _runSandboxPlugins: (ev, sb, cb) ->
    tasks =
      for p in @_plugins when typeof p.plugin?[ev] is "function" then do (p) ->
        fn = p.plugin[ev]
        (next) ->
          if util.hasArgument fn, 3
            fn sb, p.options, next
          else
            fn sb, p.options
            next()
    util.runSeries tasks, cb, true

  _startAll: (mods=(m for m of @_modules), cb) ->

    startAction = (m, next) => @start m, @_modules[m].options, next

    done = (err) ->
      if err?.length > 0
        mdls = ("'#{mods[i]}'" for x,i in err when x?)
        e = new Error "errors occoured in the following modules: #{mdls}"
      cb? e
    util.doForAll mods, startAction, done, true
    @

  stop: (id, cb=->) ->
    if arguments.length is 0 or typeof id is "function"
      util.doForAll (x for x of @_instances), (=> @stop arguments...), id, true

    else if instance = @_instances[id]

      delete @_instances[id]

      @_mediator.off instance
      @_runSandboxPlugins 'destroy', @_sandboxes[id], (err) =>

        # if the module wants destroy in an asynchronous way
        if util.hasArgument instance.destroy
          # then define a callback
          instance.destroy (err) ->
            # rereference if something went wrong
            @_instances[id] = instance if err
            cb err
        else
          # else call the callback directly after stopping
          instance.destroy?()
          cb()
    @

  # register a plugin
  use: (plugin, opt) ->
    if plugin instanceof Array
      for p in plugin
        switch typeof p
          when "function" then @use p
          when "object"   then @use p.plugin, p.options
    else
      return @ unless typeof plugin is "function"
      @_plugins.push creator:plugin, options:opt
    @

  # load plugins
  boot: (cb) ->
    core  = @
    tasks = for p in @_plugins when p.booted isnt true then do (p) ->
      if util.hasArgument p.creator, 3
        (next) ->
          plugin = p.creator core, p.options, (err) ->
            if not err
              p.booted = true
              p.plugin = plugin
            next()
      else
        (next) ->
          p.plugin = p.creator core, p.options
          p.booted = true
          next()
    util.runSeries tasks, cb, true
    @

  on:   -> @_mediator.on.apply   @_mediator, arguments
  off:  -> @_mediator.off.apply  @_mediator, arguments
  emit: -> @_mediator.emit.apply @_mediator, arguments
```

This is working quite well but reading and understanding is still not optimal.

Here are my questions:

- How could that `checkType` helper method replaced without repeating the same lines again and again?
- How could the error-handling be improved? E.g. I'd like to check a module that gets registered. Should I throw an error? Just log a warning? Returning `false` would break the chainable API.
- How could the logging be improved? Does it make sense to define a dummy logger? Or should `console.log` be used?
- How could the core be structured for better readability?
- What else could be done in a better way?
- Which parts are totally weird?